# Repeat drop down boxes - 20 in Total - Mysql - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 20 dropdown box which queries a single table and same field, I wrote the following query which works great. I am sure that there is a certain way to optimize this repetitive drop-down boxes, which I am not aware of.

Shall i write an function and the pass parameters from each `<select><? functioname() ?></select>`
[image]

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Split 1</label>
                 <select class="form-control required" name='distance[]' id='distance' >
                    <option value="-1">Select Distance</option>
                    <?php
                                                   $plan_sql="select * from mytable";
                                                   $plan_res=mysqli_query($con,$plan_sql);
                                                   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($plan_res,MYSQL_BOTH))
                                                   {
                                                       ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
                    <?php
                                                   }
                                                ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Split 2</label>
                 <select class="form-control required" name='distance[]' id='distance' >
                    <option value="-1">Select Distance</option>
                    <?php
                                                   $plan_sql="select * from mytablename";
                                                   $plan_res=mysqli_query($con,$plan_sql);
                                                   while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($plan_res,MYSQL_BOTH))
                                                   {
                                                       ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
                    <?php
                                                   }
                                                ?>
                  </select>
                </div>
```

[image]

Comment: You have a different table for every group?

Comment: It sounds like you're executing the same query repeatedly. I would run the query once and store the results so they could be reused for each of the selects.

Comment: @chris85 no same table

Comment: Does each drop-down contain the same values?

Comment: @BenM. Yes its same table, same field and same value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

// Run your query once and store the results

$plan_sql = "select id, name from mytable";
$plan_res = mysqli_query($con, $plan_sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($plan_res, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $result[] = $row;
};

// then you can add your selects without running the query repeatedly

for ($i=1; $i <= 20; $i++):?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Split <?php echo $i; ?></label>
    <select class="form-control required" name='distance[]' id='distance' >
        <option value="-1">Select Distance</option>
        <?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: I'd just change `MYSQL_BOTH` to `MYSQLI_ASSOC`.